# How Can I Retrieve the Product Image Absolute Path

Tags: magento-enterprise, image

How can I pull the product image absolute path in a product?

This returns the product along with the URL:

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(160, 128)
```

But I needed to access this the _newFile from this object:

```
    object(Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image)#3877 (14) {
  ["_model":protected] => object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image)#3876 (34) {
    ["_width":protected] => int(160)
    ["_height":protected] => int(128)
    ["_quality":protected] => int(90)
    ["_keepAspectRatio":protected] => bool(true)
    ["_keepFrame":protected] => bool(true)
    ["_keepTransparency":protected] => bool(true)
    ["_constrainOnly":protected] => bool(false)
    ["_backgroundColor":protected] => array(3) {
      [0] => int(255)
      [1] => int(255)
      [2] => int(255)
    }
    ["_baseFile":protected] => string(90) "/file/path/media/catalog/product/V/V/123.jpg"
    ["_isBaseFilePlaceholder":protected] => bool(false)
    ["_newFile":protected] => string(151) "/file/path/media/catalog/product/cache/6/small_image/160x128/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/V/V/VV123.jpg"
```

Thank you!

Comment: try this `<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->getModel()->getNewFile() ?>`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_newFile` is a member of the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image` that is a protected member of the `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image` (`$_model`).
Unfortunately there is no public method to access the `_model` member of the helper class.
Why? I have no idea. From my point of view you should be able to access it.

I see 2 options here.
**Option 1**
Rewrite the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image` with one of your classes and add this method in your class.

```
public function getModel() {
    return $this->_getModel()
}
```

[Here is a tutorial on how to rewrite a class.](http://magedev.com/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/).

After that you would be able to access what you need like this:

```
$image = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(160, 128);
$newFile = $image->getModel()->getNewFile();
```

**Option 2**
Get the url of the new image and replace the base url with the base path.

```
$image = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(160, 128);
$imageUrl = $image->__toString();
$newFile = str_replace(
    array(Mage::getBaseUrl('media'), '/'),
    array(Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS, DS),
    $imageUrl
);
```

This seams to work, but it may not work if you use a CDN.

I would go with the first option.

Comment: Was asking the same thing why they made it protected.

Comment: @user1240207. I don't have an answer for that. Maybe someone thought you don't need it outside the class. Maybe you need the helper only for resizing images.

Answer (score 0):

I have news for y'all.  In Magento 1.9.1 there is a function called **getNewFile** that will return the value of _newFile. Its located at: line 356 of **./app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php** in class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image